# Date format parse exception - "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy"

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I got problem with date parse example date:

```
SimpleDateFormat parserSDF=new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy", Locale.getDefault());


parserSDF.parse("Wed Oct 16 00:00:00 CEST 2013");
```

got exception

Exacly I want parse this format date to yyyy-MM-dd
I try:

```
SimpleDateFormat parserSDF = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);
Date date = parserSDF.parse("Wed Oct 16 00:00:00 CEST 2013");
```

take :
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Wed Oct 16 00:00:00 CEST 2013"

---

OK I change to and works :

```
SimpleDateFormat parserSDF = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
Date date = parserSDF.parse("Wed Oct 16 00:00:00 CEST 2013");
```

Comment: ParseException I guess

Comment: I run your code.there is no exception..please attach exception stack trace..

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I'm going to assume that `Locale.getDefault()` for you is `pl-PL` since you seem to be in Poland.

English words in date strings therefore cause an unparseable date.

An appropriate Polish date `String` would be something like

```
"Wt paź 16 00:00:00 -0500 2013"
```

Otherwise, change your `Locale` to `Locale.ENGLISH` so that the `SimpleDateFormat` object can parse `String` dates with English words.

Answer (score 10):

Instead of using `Locale.default` that you and others often don't know which default, you can decide by using `locale.ENGLISH` because I see your string date is format in English. If you are at other countries, the format will be different.

Here is my example code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        SimpleDateFormat parserSDF = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
        Date date = parserSDF.parse("Wed Oct 16 00:00:00 CEST 2013");
        System.out.println("date: " + date.toString());
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The result will be : `date: Wed Oct 16 05:00:00 ICT 2013`. Or you can decide which part of this date to be printed, by using its fields.

Hope this help :)

Answer (score 6):

I think the original Exception is due to `Z` in your format. 
Per [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#rfc822timezone):

```
Z   Time zone   RFC 822 time zone   -0800
```

most likely you meant to use lower case `z`

Comment: `documentation` link broken.

Comment: @Rao - fixed the link :)

Comment: Thank you for your attention and quick action to fix it. Appreciate it.