# Joda-Time invalid format

Tags: java, android, date, jodatime

I have a problem and I don't know what I am doing wrong.

I am trying to convert this String "Fri, 29 Jan 2016 10:29:54 +0100" to DateTime object.

I set this pattern for this type of date: "EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"

Application still is thowing me `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException()` and I don't know why...

Function is succeeding:

```
    public static String getTimeFromPublicDate(String date) {
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");

    try {
        DateTime dateTime = DateTime.parse(date, formatter);
        return dateTime.getDayOfMonth()
                +"/"+ dateTime.getMonthOfYear()+"/"+ dateTime.getYear();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

And stackTrace:

```
01-29 15:32:25.739 30825-30825/pl.antyradio20 W/System.err:     at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseDateTime(DateTimeFormatter.java:945)
01-29 15:32:25.739 30825-30825/pl.antyradio20 W/System.err:     at org.joda.time.DateTime.parse(DateTime.java:160)
01-29 15:32:25.739 30825-30825/pl.antyradio20 W/System.err:     at pl.antyradio20.model.NewsData.getTimeFromPublicDate(NewsData.java:63)
01-29 15:32:25.739 30825-30825/pl.antyradio20 W/System.err:     at pl.antyradio20.view.adapter.newsAdapter.twoImages.TwoImagesAdapter.onBindViewHolder(TwoImagesAdapter.java:72)
01-29 15:32:25.739 30825-30825/pl.antyradio20 W/System.err:     at pl.antyradio20.view.adapter.newsAdapter.twoImages.TwoImagesAdapter.onBindViewHolder(TwoImagesAdapter.java:18)
01-29 15:32:25.739 30825-30825/pl.antyradio20 W/System.err:     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5217)
01-29 15:32:25.739 30825-30825/pl.antyradio20 W/System.err:     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5250)
01-29 15:32:25.739 30825-30825/pl.antyradio20 W/System.err:     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4487)
01-29 15:32:25.739 30825-30825/pl.antyradio20 W/System.err:     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4363)
01-29 15:32:25.739 30825-30825/pl.antyradio20 W/System.err:     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1961)
01-29 15:32:25.739 30825-30825/pl.antyradio20 W/System.err:     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1370)
01-29 15:32:25.739 30825-30825/pl.antyradio20 W/System.err:     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1333)
01-29 15:32:25.739 30825-30825/pl.antyradio20 W/System.err:     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.scrollBy(LinearLayoutManager.java:1161)
01-29 15:32:25.739 30825-30825/pl.antyradio20 W/System.err:     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.scrollVerticallyBy(LinearLayoutManager.java:1018)
01-29 15:32:25.739 30825-30825/pl.antyradio20 W/System.err:     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewFlinger.run(RecyclerView.java:3807)
01-29 15:32:25.739 30825-30825/pl.antyradio20 W/System.err:     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
01-29 15:32:25.739 30825-30825/pl.antyradio20 W/System.err:     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
01-29 15:32:25.739 30825-30825/pl.antyradio20 W/System.err:     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:549)
01-29 15:32:25.739 30825-30825/pl.antyradio20 W/System.err:     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
01-29 15:32:25.739 30825-30825/pl.antyradio20 W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
01-29 15:32:25.739 30825-30825/pl.antyradio20 W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
01-29 15:32:25.739 30825-30825/pl.antyradio20 W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
01-29 15:32:25.739 30825-30825/pl.antyradio20 W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5376)
01-29 15:32:25.739 30825-30825/pl.antyradio20 W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-29 15:32:25.739 30825-30825/pl.antyradio20 W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
01-29 15:32:25.739 30825-30825/pl.antyradio20 W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908)
01-29 15:32:25.739 30825-30825/pl.antyradio20 W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)
```

Comment: Please add the code and the complete stack trace to help you in any way possible.

Comment: replica of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19861642/date-format-parse-exception-eee-mmm-dd-hhmmss-z-yyyy

Comment: @KinjalPatel sorry but I don't see any similarity between my question and question which You mentioned. I use Joda Time, and in Your post I don't see any solution on my problem.

Comment: @Phani I added code and complete stack trace. Please help, because I don't know where is a mistake.