# How to convert a custom Date Time string to milliseconds using Joda Time?

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

How can I create an instance of `java.util.Date` out of a custom date time string?
This is what I tried so far:

Given I have the this custom date time string:

```
Fri Jul 29 12:56:35 UTC 2022
```

Using Joda-Time in the following piece of code:

```
String time = "Fri Jul 29 12:56:35 UTC 2022";
DateTimeFormatter df = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
long millis = df.parseMillis(time);
```

I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "Fri Jul 29 12:56:35 UTC 2022" is malformed at " UTC 2022"
        at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseMillis(DateTimeFormatter.java:644)
```

Comment: Isn’t it a locale problem? Your string is in English, so if your default locale isn’t, it will likely cause parsing to fail. Does `DateTimeFormat.forPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy").withLocale(Locale.ROOT)` work for you? Similar: [java DateTimeFormatterBuilder fails on testtime \[duplicate\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50526234/java-datetimeformatterbuilder-fails-on-testtime).

Comment: Please, except if for use with a legacy API that you cannot change, do not create a `java.util.Date`. It’s for your own sake. That class is so poorly designed, nothing we want to deal with. Either stick with Joda-Time or follow the official Joda-Time recommendation and migrate to java.time.

Comment: Similar: [Joda-Time invalid format \[duplicate\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35086527/joda-time-invalid-format). Unfortunately that one is unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a code like this :

```
String time = "Fri Jul 29 12:56:35 UTC 2022";
Date date = new Date(time);
long millis = date.getTime();
System.out.println(millis);
```