# Cannot parse datestring with SimpleDateFormat ParseException

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I want to parse a **String** into a **Date**, but my **SimpleDateFormat** doesn't work.
Everytime I get a ParseException.
Whats wrong with my SimpleDateFormat? The datestring I want to parse looks like this:

`Mon Dec 17 00:00:00 CET 2012`

```
public Date toLongDate(String date) {
    try {
        return date != null ? new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy").parse(date) : null;
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("cannot parse date " + date);
    }
}
```

best regards

Comment: look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19861642/date-format-parse-exception-eee-mmm-dd-hhmmss-z-yyyy

Comment: The code does not throw any exception unless the locale used is collided.

Answer (score 2):

Try doing with locale as argument:

```
final String sss = "Mon Dec 17 00:00:00 CET 2012";
final Date d = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.US).parse(sss);
System.out.println(d);
```

Output:

> Mon Dec 17 00:00:00 CET 2012

Comment: Why `final` variables?

Comment: remove it if you want/need to change the value latter, for me is an autoformat in eclipse

Comment: Thanks, the missing Locale is the answer.