# SimpleDateFormat convert String to Date in Java

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I tried to use simpleDateFormat to convert the original format of Date string back to Date.

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
Date a = format.parse(nowTest);
```

nowTest is a string `Fri Mar 18 15:02:38 EDT 2016`

But console told me that

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Fri Mar 18 15:02:38 EDT 2016"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:366)
```

I can't figure out why this format doesn't work.
Thank you in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19861642/date-format-parse-exception-eee-mmm-dd-hhmmss-z-yyyy

Comment: Thank you so much. I also have a question about the format of day. Since I use dd to present, but I don't know whether the default format of Date is dd. Like 9th is default 9 or 09. ? OH I figure it out. Thank you Soooo much