# Need help parsing String into date

Tags: java, date, exception

So I get this String ("Tue Nov 26 12:05:19 CET 2019") from a txt fiel and I want to parse it into a Date like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
Date date = null;

try {
    date = format.parse(dateAsString);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And I still get this Exception:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Tue Nov 26 12:05:19 CET 2019"
```

But the format/patter should be ok. So my question is how I parse the string into a date.

Comment: What is your JVM and operating system locale? Could it be that it's not English so `Tue` and `Nov` are not parsed?

Comment: Can you update your entire code? I tried doing the same but it was working fine.

Comment: What do you get if you run this line of code: `System.out.println(java.util.Locale.getDefault());`

Comment: See this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19861642/date-format-parse-exception-eee-mmm-dd-hhmmss-z-yyyy

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `ZonedDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set language as English here

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
Date date = null;

try {
    date = format.parse("Tue Nov 26 12:05:19 CET 2019");
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println(date);
```

Answer (score 3):

You are most likely not using English locale so `Tue` and `Nov` are not parsing. Specify the locale with the formatter and don't use obsolete date classes:

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", Locale.US);
ZonedDateTime time = ZonedDateTime.parse("Tue Nov 26 12:05:19 CET 2019", fmt);
System.out.println(time); // 2019-11-26T12:05:19+01:00[Europe/Paris]
```

Comment: You assume the OP is using at least JDK 1.8. Also it's not clear to me from your answer that the code you posted is using the new Date-Time API that was added in JDK 1.8

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = 
    new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", new Locale("en", "EN"));
```